# Error in file reading in android

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String args[])
{
    String numbers[];
    numbers = new String[81];


    try {
            FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream("level.txt");
            int r,index=0;
            char y;
            while ((r = fileInput.read()) != -1) {
               y = (char)r;
               numbers[index++] = y + "";
            }
        }catch(Exception e){System.out.println("you are pawned !!");}

        for(int i=0;i<81;i++)
        System.out.println(numbers[i].length());
}
}
```

The above code is working perfectly fine in Java but as I use it in android it gives error - "Unfortunately the device has stopped working". Also "Test.java" and "level.txt" are in same folder so I don't see any reason why it isn't working in android.

Comment: Do you have the permission to write/read to device storage?

Comment: How do you "use it in android"? It is not an `Activity` and cannot be run directly. Also, please provide the logcat.

Comment: Hey, can you review answers and try them? then choose to accept one of them.

Comment: I have got the solution .. it's that I can either store the "txt" file in /asset or in /raw and then use getAssets() function or getResources() respectively. Thanks all !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as "Test.java and level.txt are in same folder" in the android architecture.

In android there is internal and external storage. that you can get its root directory in two different ways.

External storage (sdcard folder): here you don't have to save the file in using code unlike internal memory. you can just move it to your sd card.

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/level.txt";
FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream(path);
```

Internal memory (app private disk)

```
String path this.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + name;
FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream(path);
```

Give permission to your app to read/write from external memory by adding this to minifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

And there is alot of places inside the app that you can put your file in. like the assets and raw folder.

Get stream of a file in the assets folder:

```
InputStream is = this.getAssets().open("level.txt");
```

Get stream of a file in the raw folder:

```
InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.level);
```

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot ... that's the way I have found out on other sites. Dealing with a file differs in java and android.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, this code is not an Android code, so i will assume that you will copy/paste the content of your method in the onCreate() method in your main activity

second, you are reading from a file, where is this file on your device ? is it in your assets folder for example, or on the SD, or where !?

this File doesnt even exist on the mobile device, so how can it access it ... a simple way to deal with File IO in android is using the

```
getDir()
```

for example :

```
File directory = getDir() // from your activity
File file = new File(directory,"level.txt");
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
// and so on
```

Comment: i didnt test this code, but you can consider it a psuedocode that may help, i cant remember the exact syntax for the getDir() method

Comment: I have got the solution .. it's that I can either store the "txt" file in /asset or in /raw and then use getAssets() function or getResources() respectively. Thanks all !!